# Excel Fill blank rows with values from above

Tags: excel, excel-formula, flood-fill, vba

Looking to fill blank values in a row with the 'top' value, similar to the functionality provided by [Editing>Fill>Top](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-74e31bdd-d993-45da-aa82-35a236c5b5db). The difference being that the Fill function requires you to go row-by-row rather than applying itself to a larger dataset. Example below:

```
Apple   1   foo
Banana  1   foo
        2   foo
            bar
Cherry  2   bar
        3   foo
        6   bar
Grape   1   foo
```

Would end up as the following:

```
Apple   1   foo
Banana  1   foo
Banana* 2   foo
Banana* 2*  bar
Cherry  2   bar
Cherry* 3   foo
Cherry* 6   bar
Grape   1   foo       //new values represented with *
```

Note that the third entry in the second column (`2`) was also brought down implying this could be applied to multiple columns.

The value in this would be converting a table that has the relationships `Cherry>2, Cherry>3, Cherry>6` represented in the first table into a format that could be used as an associative table.

Comment: What's this got to do with MySQL?

Comment: It was in the recommended, and I'm going back and forth to MySQL - mistakenly added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this short macro:

```
Sub FillInTheBlanks()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, j As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To N
        For j = 1 To 2
            If Cells(i, j).Value = "" Then Cells(i, j).Value = Cells(i, j).Offset(-1, 0).Value
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought id add my variation on this one. Works when you just want to select a range

```
Sub BlankCellAll()

For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:R14").Cells
 
 If c.Value = "" Then c.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
 
 c.Value = c.Value
 
  
 Next

End Sub
```